# pip tries to use git when git is not installed

Tags: python, git, pip

I have a project folder that is a git repository (has a .git folder). When I use the command `pip freeze`, pip tries to use git. However, I don't have git installed on my system so this causes an error:

```
(env) PS C:\Users\eclaird\work\myproject> pip freeze
Cannot find command 'git'
Storing complete log in C:\Users\eclaird\pip\pip.log
(env) PS C:\Users\eclaird\work\myproject>
```

pip.log:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\eclaird\work\env\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 01/09/14 11:54:42
Cannot find command 'git'
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eclaird\work\env\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\eclaird\work\env\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\freeze.py", line 73, in run
    req = pip.FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist, dependency_links, find_tags=find_tags)
  File "C:\Users\eclaird\work\env\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 180, in from_dist
    req = get_src_requirement(dist, location, find_tags)
  File "C:\Users\eclaird\work\env\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\__init__.py", line 249, in get_src_requirement
    return version_control().get_src_requirement(dist, location, find_tags)
  File "C:\Users\eclaird\work\env\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\git.py", line 151, in get_src_requirement
    repo = self.get_url(location)
  File "C:\Users\eclaird\work\env\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\git.py", line 122, in get_url
    [self.cmd, 'config', 'remote.origin.url'],
  File "C:\Users\eclaird\work\env\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\__init__.py", line 110, in cmd
    command = find_command(self.name)
  File "C:\Users\eclaird\work\env\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 108, in find_command
    raise BadCommand('Cannot find command %r' % cmd)
BadCommand: Cannot find command 'git'
```

Is there a way to disable the git integration in pip?

(pip 1.4.1, 
Python 2.7.6)

Comment: When using git repositories pip simply requires git, it'd be a bit of a waste to make pip implement it's own git reader when the git binary already does this perfectly. Installing the git tools under windows is easy using the github installer though, perhaps that's a valid workaround for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is no config option to enable/disable backends.

Details, found by digging in the code:

**Git module is always registered:** In [pip/**install**.py](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/1.4.1/pip/__init__.py), the [git module](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/1.4.1/pip/vcs/git.py) is imported. At the end of it, it registers itself, and will thus be queried whenever one of the schemes declared in ´git.Git´ matches the url of the dependency.

```
schemes = ('git', 'git+http', 'git+https', 'git+ssh', 'git+git', 'git+file')
```

**Exception is not handled** Funnily, freezing anticipates that an error might occur when determining the dependency url to be frozen. Excerpt from [pip.FrozenRequirement](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/1.4.1/pip/__init__.py#L181):

```
try:
    req = get_src_requirement(dist, location, find_tags)
except InstallationError:
    logger.warn("Error when trying to get requirement for VCS system %s, falling back to uneditable format" % ex)
```

[InstallationError inherits from PipError](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/1.4.1/pip/exceptions.py#L8). Unfortunately, an exception of type ´BadCommand´ is raised, which inherits from ´PipError´.

So, aside from hacking the source: Nothing you can do. If you need this to work, you need to install git, hack the source, or simulate a git executable. If you go for the latter, for starters you need to fake ´git config remote.origin.url´, which is called (and fails) in [pip.vcs.git.Git.get_url](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/1.4.1/pip/vcs/git.py#L120).

Hope that helps, even though it's not a *yes*. ;)